# Find and Replace the node inner text in C#.net using XML Reader

Tags: c#, filestream, xmldocument, xmlreader, xmlnode

I've been writing below code to find and replace the wrong values with right one.

I've two files here, Source=Delimited text file like below.

```
J48309A0580113A27E053A2DEF40AC8B8,Z9e578475,
7e241974c714459997e20fe6e195ffb1,BD17946 and BD38168,
```

and my destination xmlJRN file looks like below. (multiple xmlJRN files)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE eGAD SYSTEM "eGAD.Dtd">
<eGAD pakUID="PID_77F0F469AFE61B4A8121AA84EB349B6C">
  <document docID="1" docMasterID="1A5D331DDF8A84385F77B621C3F9CD86" docInstanceID="49E3D61E9CE1DF43BDD042F296913C88">
    <VendorId>7618CEADE31441C99FE1BC07E325E0FA</VendorId>
    <DocTypeId>CE3CD095580647389ED402675B43BE16</DocTypeId>
    <AccNo>TXT:</AccNo>
    <StmtDate>20161128</StmtDate>
    <DDSDocValue name="UniqueDocID" type="text" len="32">J48309A0580113A27E053A2DEF40AC8B8</DDSDocValue>
    <NumberOfPages value="8"/>
    <Skipped>
      <SPages></SPages>
    </Skipped>
  </document>
  <document docID="1" docMasterID="1A5D331DDF8A84385F77B621C3F9CD86" docInstanceID="49E3D61E9CE1DF43BDD042F296913C88">
    <VendorId>7618CEADE31441C99FE1BC07E325E0FA</VendorId>
    <DocTypeId>CE3CD095580647389ED402675B43BE16</DocTypeId>
    <AccNo>TXT:1</AccNo>
    <StmtDate>20161128</StmtDate>
    <DDSDocValue name="UniqueDocID" type="text" len="32">P48309A0580113A27E053A2DEF40AC8B8</DDSDocValue>
    <NumberOfPages value="8"/>
    <Skipped>
      <SPages></SPages>
    </Skipped>
  </document>
</eGAD>
```

What I try to do is, I read the first GUID from text file and compare it with each JRNxml's document group and if I found match means, i'll replace the  innertext value with text files second value.

Below is my code

```
static void Main()
{
    //Load the File
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\temp1\\AllXMLData_FinalOutput.txt"))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] value = new string[0];

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Load the file and read the GUID and Plan number one by one From Source Text file
            var values = line.Split(',');

            string GUIDfromTxt = values[0];  // Holds the GUID value from the Source Txt file
            string PlanNofromTxt = values[1]; // Holds the Plan number valuse from the Source Txt file

            // Read the XML's one by one from Destination folder and search for the GUID on each group
            string folderPath = "C:\\Temp2";
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.JRN");

            foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
            {
                XmlDocument xmljrndoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlNodeList xmlnode;                     
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);  // Open file
                xmljrndoc.Load(fs);
                xmlnode = xmljrndoc.GetElementsByTagName("document");
                string JRNGUID = "";
                string JRNPLAN = "";

                for (int k = 0; k < xmlnode.Count; k++)                      // Read all the elements one by one
                { 
                    JRNGUID= xmlnode[k].SelectSingleNode("DDSDocValue[@name='UniqueDocID']").InnerText.Trim();   //get guid value from Destination XML
                    JRNPLAN= xmlnode[k].SelectSingleNode("AccNo").InnerText.Trim();                              //get Plan number value from Destination XML

                    Console.WriteLine("Value From Text File GUID : " + GUIDfromTxt + " Plan Number : " + PlanNofromTxt);
                    Console.WriteLine("Value From JRN File GUID : " + JRNGUID + " Plan Number : " + JRNPLAN);

                    if ((GUIDfromTxt == JRNGUID) && (JRNPLAN.Length <= 8)) // check the GUID matches
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("OLD Value : "+ JRNPLAN + " NEW Value : " + PlanNofromTxt);                           xmlnode[k].SelectSingleNode("AccNo").InnerText.Replace(JRNPLAN, PlanNofromTxt); //  replace the txt plan to xml plan tag
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Xml JRN Value after find and replace " + JRNGUID + " " + JRNPLAN);                           
                }

                fs.Close();
                //fs.Dispose();

            }

            Console.ReadKey(); 
        }
        //reader.Close();
        //reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This code is not working in last part means, unable to replace the text in xmlJRN file.

Can some one help me to find the mistake I have done here? you help is much appreciated. I want to replace a value and save files.

EDIT1:
Thanks for your suggestions, I've completed the code. Here is the final one.

```
static void Main()
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp3\\Log.txt", false, Encoding.ASCII);  // log file declaration

    string folderPath = "C:\\Temp2";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.JRN");

    foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Opening XML JRN File : " + fi.Name);

        XmlDocument xmljrndoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        xmljrndoc.Load(fs);
        xmlnode = xmljrndoc.GetElementsByTagName("document");
        string JRNGUID = "";
        string JRNPLAN = "";

        for (int k = 0; k < xmlnode.Count; k++)                      // Read all the elements one by one
        {
            JRNGUID = xmlnode[k].SelectSingleNode("DDSDocValue[@name='UniqueDocID']").InnerText.Trim();   //get guid value from Destination XML
            JRNPLAN = xmlnode[k].SelectSingleNode("AccNo").InnerText.Trim();

            sw.WriteLine("FROM XMLJRN file - GUID : " + JRNGUID + " PlanNumber : " + JRNPLAN);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\temp1\\AllXMLData_FinalOutput.txt");
            sw.WriteLine("Reading Txt file for GUID Search... ");
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] value = new string[0];

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Load the file and read the GUID and Plan number one by one
                var values = line.Split(',');

                string GUIDfromTxt = values[0];  // Holds the GUID value from the Txt file
                string PlanNofromTxt = "Compass:" + values[1]; // Holds the Plan number valuse from the Txt file

                sw.WriteLine("FROM text file - GUID : " + GUIDfromTxt + " PlanNumber : " + PlanNofromTxt);

                if ((GUIDfromTxt == JRNGUID) && (JRNPLAN.Length <= 8))                                  // check the GUID matches
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("GUID MATCH FOUND!");
                    sw.WriteLine("OLD Value : " + JRNPLAN + " replaced with  NEW Value : " + PlanNofromTxt);
                    fs.Close();
                    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

                    xmljrndoc.Save(@"C:\\Temp3\\" + fi.Name); //  replace the txt plan to xml plan tag
                    fs1.Close();

                    // xmljrndoc.Save(fi.FullName);

                }
                else
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("GUID MATCH NOT FOUND!");
                }

            }

        }
    }
            sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: I would advise implementing `using` blocks for all of your streaming objects.

Comment: what it does when you use "Using" block then the normal one?

Answer (score 0):

String.Replace does not actually modify the string directly.  It returns a copy of the string with the replacement.  You still need to assign the modified value to InnerText yourself.

For example, instead of:

```
xmlnode[k].SelectSingleNode("AccNo").InnerText.Replace(JRNPLAN, PlanNofromTxt);
```

you need to do something like:

```
var node = xmlnode[k].SelectSingleNode("AccNo");
node.InnerText = node.InnerText.Replace(JRNPLAN, PlanNofromTxt);
```

Comment: do you have any ref, I can see somewhere Rick? any link I refer.. should help me

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx explains String.Replace.  I edited answer to provide an example that will hopefully help clarify what I meant.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Mate, I've already completed this one! will share my final code here.